# How to increase limit for "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite"

Tags: typescript

I have a complex mapped type and its not infinite in any way.

If the source type is large and I use it as generic argument to my complex mapped type, then I sometimes hit "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite".

I use `infer` combined with `type Cast<T, CastType> = T extends CastType ? T : CastType` all over the place to increase the limit, but it does not get me far enough, like:

```
type ComplexMapping<Source> = (<mapping here>) extends infer M 
  ? Cast<M, any> // I set a specific type if possible
  : never
```

What methods can I use to increase the limit?

Also, do a typed generic argument (`MyType<T extends Typed> = {}`) increase the depth of the type instantiation?

Comment: [Microsoft/TypeScript#28663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28663) and [Microsoft/TypeScript#31619](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31619) are relevant? Don't know of any general method for fixing it, other than trying to get concrete types as soon as possible.  I feel this question is a bit broad; it might help to have a [mcve] someone can play with. Not sure what version of TS you're using either; in 3.4 this got noticeably worse, but has been [improved](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-checking-speed-ups) in 3.5.

Comment: I wish that I could provide en minimal reproducible example, but the nature of my problem is a large complex type like JSON Schema, but more features and a fit for TypeScript.
I am using TS 3.5.1.