# When does TS count a type instantiation (related to error: “Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite”)?

Tags: typescript

I'm using TS 3.5.1 and having a problem with “Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite” for a complex mapping type.

I have already battled for days trying to optimized the type to the my best of knownledge about the issue.

When and where does TypeScript count type instantiation? Is it each time a generic type is involved? Does it also include all types in a union result from a mapped generic type? Does it count all "conditions" in generic type mapping or only until it match? Does a union of X types as argument to a generic type count as X type instantiation or 1 type instantiation?

Background info:
The type in question is somewhat similar and inspired by JSON Schema. It maps a schema declaration to a concrete type, so there is a limit of how much complexity I can get rid of before hurting its core functionality.

Here's an example of a declaration:

```
const someDeclaration = {
  type: 'Object'
  required: true
  additionalProperties: false
  trim: false
  properties: {
    prop1: {
      type: 'Object'
      required: true
      additionalProperties: false
      trim: true
      properties: {
        prop2: {
          type: 'Array'
          required: false
          items: { type: 'Number' }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} as const
```

It results in this type:

```
{
  readonly prop1: {
    readonly prop2?: ReadonlyArray<number> | undefined;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think when it hits depth 30 which is  depth hardcoded by the compiler, however i may be mistaken because i remember in the back of my mind something to do with the number "5"

Comment: Is this question sufficiently different from [your other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416316/how-to-increase-limit-for-type-instantiation-is-excessively-deep-and-possibly-i) that you need both of them open?

Comment: The depth limit is 50.